# Redis issue on module-redis-fork

Tags: redis, node-redis, redisearch

#### Issue

Hi everyone,

I have an issue while trying to interact with  Redis in those conditions:

1. Redis instance with **Redisearch module**,
2. **Create** node-redis **client before Redis module fork is ongoing**,
3. Redis module fork is on-going

The behaviour that I get is that "send_command" stays idle until the fork stops.
When the fork ends I get this error:

debug mode ->

```
Redis connection is gone from end event
```

client error ->

```
AbortError: Redis connection lost and command aborted. It might have been processed.
```

After I get this error the commands **from the same client (without creating a new client)** come back to works fine.

On every fork, I got the same behaviour.

**Additional Info:**

```
keys: 37773168,
used_memory_human: '87.31G'
```

---

#### Code Example:

This is a simple express app,

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const Redis = require('redis');
// Redis.debug_mode = true;
const router = express.Router();

let client = null;

router.get('/redisearch/connect', async (req, res, next) => {
    const conf = {
        'host': '127.0.0.1',
        'port': 6379,
        'db': 0,
    };

    try {
        if (!client) client = Redis.createClient(conf.port, conf.host, { db: conf.db });
        res.send('Connected');
    } catch (err) {
        res.send(err);
    }
});

router.get('/redisearch/d', async (req, res, next) => {
    const num = 10;
    const dArgs = ['testIndexName', `@ic:[${num} ${num}]`, 'GROUPBY', 1, '@d'];

    try {
        client.send_command('FT.AGGREGATE', dArgs, (err, reply) => {
            if (err) {
                res.send({ err: err });
            };
            res.send({ d: reply });
        });
    } catch (err) {
        res.send(err);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

this is the simplest way I have to replicate the problem.

I don't know if there is a way to force redis to use the fork, in my case it appears following a massive search on index followed by delete and insert of records.

Redis however during these operations (insert/delete) works normally,
I can launch commands from the redis-cli;

By creating a new instance of the node-redis client while the fork is present everything works normally and when the fork goes away everything keep working.

#### Environment

- **Node.js Version**: `v14.15.1`

- **Redis Version**:  `6.0.4`

- **redisearch Version**:  `1.6.15`

- **node-redis Version**: `3.2`

- **Platform**: `Server 128GB RAM, 8 Core, Debian`

Comment: Can you please share the relevant code?

Comment: @LeibaleEidelman i've updated the post with the code.